# How to create flattened JSON output using LINQ and C#?

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code, I am new to LINQ and C#:

```
var result = (from x in _context.DwPropertyMasters
              where
              x.ShowMapPoint == "Y"
              select new
              {
 x.LandId,
                  x.MapPointX,
                x.MapPointY,
                 c = from z in _context.DwPropertyDetails
                      where (z.TransactionPrice > 0 || z.TransactionPrice != null) && z.LandId == x.LandId
                      group z by z.LandId into g
                      select new
                      {
                          c = (g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice)) / (g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize))
                      },
              }).ToArray();
```

The output should like this:

```
[
    {
        "LandId": 1,
        "MapPointX": "22.37607871816074",
        "MapPointY": "113.96758139133453",
        "c": 13198
    }
]
```

But I got this:

```
[
    {
        "LandId": 1,
        "MapPointX": "22.37607871816074",
        "MapPointY": "113.96758139133453",
        "c": [
            {
                "c": 13198
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What title is this? It cannot be any worse.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a `new` object. Just select what you want to get.

```
var result = (from x in _context.DwPropertyMasters
              where
              x.ShowMapPoint == "Y"
              select new
              {
                  x.LandId,
                  x.MapPointX,
                  x.MapPointY,
                  c = (from z in _context.DwPropertyDetails
                      where (z.TransactionPrice > 0 || z.TransactionPrice != null) && z.LandId == x.LandId
                      group z by z.LandId into g
                      select (g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice)) / (g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize)))
                     .First()
              }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice answer! Thank You.But I got an output like this. "c":[13198]

Comment: Because you're fetching an array, you will need to grab the first element. Linq `.First()` would be the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you so much FrannkerZ, It works too I use .FirstOrDefault() instead. One more thing. I got an output like this.                                            [
    {
        "LandId": 1,
        "MapPointX": "22.37607871816074",
        "MapPointY": "113.96758139133453",
        "c": 13198
    }
] but I want is like this [ 
    1,
    22.37607871816074,
    113.96758139133453,
    13198,
] how to do this? please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Grouping doesn't produce just one item.  It produces one item for each group, regardless of how many groups are produced.  Yes, you're filtering DwPropertyDetails to just one LandId, by group doesn't know that and will produce an array of grouping with one item.

In your example if you put a FirstOrDefault after the Linq expression that computes c then it should be good.:

```
var result = (from x in _context.DwPropertyMasters
            where
            x.ShowMapPoint == "Y"
            select new float[]
            {
                x.LandId,
                x.MapPointX,
                x.MapPointY,
                (from z in _context.DwPropertyDetails
                    where (z.TransactionPrice > 0 || z.TransactionPrice != null) && z.LandId == x.LandId
                    group z by z.LandId into g
                    select new
                    {
                        c = (g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice)) / (g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize))
                    }).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToArray();
```

The gotcha in this bit of code is in the select new.  As you have written it C# will create an anonymous class object with named fields.  It's useful a lot of the time but you want to create an array, so change the

> select new

to

> select new float[]

So that the compiler knows that you want an array and not an anonymous class object.  Since you're just interested in the value for c you don't want to name the value, and because you only want one value from the inner (from z in ...) then use First() or FirstOrDefault() to get just the first (and only) value instead of a 1-element list of values

This expression returns an array of arrays.  If you want just the first array then tack on a FirstOrDefault() just before the ToArray() at the end

Comment: Thank you Ray Fischer :)

Comment: I got an output like this.                                                                            [ { "LandId": 1, "MapPointX": "22.37607871816074", "MapPointY": "113.96758139133453", "c": 13198 } ]                                                         but I want is like this                                                                                 [ 1, 22.37607871816074, 113.96758139133453, 13198, ]                   how to do this? please help me :(